# Mistake in potential function for dynamic table contraction in CLRS?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

In the third edition of "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen et al ("CLRS"), section 17.4 ("Dynamic tables") is an overview of amortized analysis as it relates to managing the array-backed storage of a table of values.

I'm particularly concerned about the analysis of the `TABLE-REMOVE` algorithm: either I'm misunderstanding the text (very likely) or there's a mistake.

So far, the text has shown that if the existing array is full in `TABLE-INSERT` then allocating a new array of twice the size results in an amortized running time of $O(1)$ for insertion operations.

Using the potential energy method for accounting, the potential function is defined as

\begin{equation}
\Phi(T)=2\cdot N - |T|
\end{equation}
where $N$ is the number of items stored in the table and $|T|$ denotes the capacity of the underlying array.

We can see that immediately after the table is expanded the array is exactly half full and so $2\cdot N - |T| = |T| - |T| = 0$ (that is, we've used up all our stored energy to "pay" for the expansion).

Now, we need to shrink the table when deleting items so that we don't waste space. I'm suitably convinced by the book's intuitive argument that the right time to shrink the table by half is when, after deletion, the array is less than 1/4 full.

Here's the problem. The book says:

> As the load factor deviates from $1/2$, the potential increases so that by the time we expand or contract the table, the table has garnered sufficient potential to pay for copying all the items into the newly allocated table. [...] Thus, we will need a potential function that has grown to T.num by the time that the load factor has either increased to 1 or decreased to $1/4$. **After either expanding or contracting the table, the load factor goes back to $1/2$ and the table's potential reduces back to 0.**

(Emphasis mine.)

and we amend the potential function to account for deletion as follows:

\begin{equation}
\Phi(T) =
\begin{cases}
2\cdot N - |T|, & \alpha(T) \ge 1/2\\
\frac{|T|}{2} - N, & \alpha(T) \lt 1/2\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Suppose that the array has capacity for 32 items (ie., $|T| = 32$) and just before we call `TABLE-REMOVE` there are 8 items (ie., $N = 8$). After deleting an item (by decrementing the `num` member of `T`) the load factor is now less than $1/4$ so we shrink the table: now $|T| = 16$ and $N = 7$.

Our potential function evaluates to $16/2 - 7 = 1 \ne 0$ and the load factor is $\alpha = 7/16 \ne 1/2$. This contradicts the text.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that if we insert the new item immediately after expansion then the potential isn't zero either. Does it depend on if we define expansion or contraction as separate operations? I think I'm very confused.

Comment: If you shrink the data structure once the load factor hits $1/4$, then the potential does get to zero exactly.

Comment: I suggest not taking the bolded comment too literally. The only thing which is important is that the potential function is always non-negative. It hits zero, or very close to zero, after expanding and shrinking.